# Can I allow a standard user to execute only certain sets of command in terminal?

Tags: command-line, permissions, users, restricted-access

Can I create a whitelist of commands that a standard user can execute in the terminal in Ubuntu 12.04 desktop?

I don't want to block the terminal for the standard user.

Comment: PLEASE START MARKING ANSWERS AS "ACCEPTED" IF INDEED THEY DO ANSWER YOUR QUERY.

Comment: Can you give us examples of the commands you want to whitelist or blacklist?  Most commands which can have a significant effect on the system can only be run by **root** or an administrator.

Comment: rishab, you got answers for many [questions you made](http://askubuntu.com/users/171976/rishab-v?tab=questions) but you didn't marked any one as "accepted". If an answer helps you, upvote it. If an answer "works for you" mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it. Please take the Ask Ubuntu [tour](http://askubuntu.com/about).

Comment: This is the essentially the same as your other question, see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new group, let say `restricted_group`:

```
groupadd restricted_group
```

Add the user (that you don't wish to to have access some commands) to `restricted_group`:

```
usermod -aG restricted_group restricted_user
```

Use the `chgrp` command to change the group of `/path_to_directory_with_restricted_commands/restricted_command` to `restricted_group`:

```
chgrp restricted_group /path_to_directory_with_restricted_commands/restricted_command
```

Finally, use the `chmod` command to change file permission:

```
chmod 750 /path_to_directory_with_restricted_commands/restricted_command
```

You can also apply permissions to directory:

```
chmod 0640 /path_to_directory_with_restricted_commands
```

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/protect-command-by-configuring-linux-unix-group-permissions/